# Schedule cron job to run at different hour everyday

Tags: cron

I have a cron job scheduled to run at 7 AM in the morning, Monday to Friday `0 7 * * 1-5`. Is it possible to schedule the job to run at different hours in different days of the week. ex. 7 AM on Monday, 8 AM on Tuesday so on and so forth. Can I do it by using comma separated values like `0 7 * * 1, 0 8 * * 2` would that work?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add separate entries for each day.

Or engineer some day awareness with appropriate `sleep` into a wrapper script and use that to invoke your job.